# How to differentiate $2\left | x \right |$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

According to the answer of my calculus textbook, the derivative of $2\left | x \right |$ is $2x\left | x \right |^{-1}$, but why?

Here is the answer:

[image]

Comment: Is $x$ a real or a complex variable?

Comment: a real variable

Comment: Sure, it is derivative.

Comment: The answer you now included seems very clear. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Why the derivative of $2\left | x \right |$ is $2x\left | x \right |^{-1}$?. Especially, the second line, $2x(x^{2})^{-1/2}$, in the answer.

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia, take a look at the regret's response. This result works for $x \neq 0$, where the function has not derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the edited question. The following assumes that $x\neq 0$, since $(\sqrt{x})'$ does not exist at $x=0$.
$$(2|x|)' = (2\sqrt{x^2})' = 2(\sqrt{x^2})'$$
Then by the chain rule set $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=x^2$, so $f'(x)=1/(2\sqrt{x})$ and $g'(x)=2x$ so
$$\require{cancel}
2(\sqrt{x^2})' = 2(f(g(x)))' = 2f'(g(x))g'(x)=\cancel{2}\frac{1}{\cancel{2}\sqrt{x^2}}\cdot2x = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{2x}{|x|} = 2x|x|^{-1}.$$

Comment: Wow! Great explanation! ;-)

Comment: Yep, but this seems closer to the answer provided by my book.

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia I'm glad if it helped. Alex, Yep, of course. I will edit to make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

$x|x|^{-1}$ is just $1$ or $-1$, depending on the sign of $x$. $2|x|$ decreases linearly when $x$ is negative and increases linearly when $x$ is positive, so the derivative is just $-2$ when $x<0$ and $2$ when $x>0$.

Some equivalent ways of saying it:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}2|x|=2x|x|^{-1}=2|x|x^{-1}=2\frac{x}{|x|}=2\frac{|x|}{x}=2\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\cases{-2&if $x<0$\\2&if $x>0$}$$

It is important to note that the function is not differentiable at $0$, though.

Comment: You may want to add that your solution is equivalent to $\frac{2x}{|x|}$ (which is equivalent to $2x|x|^{-1}$, as OP specifies).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $2|x|$ for $x<0$ and $x>0$ separately and think about the meaning of the absolute value. What happens at $x=0$? If your book has nothing to say about it, throw it away ;-)

Edit: $|x| = \begin{cases}-x, & x\leq0,\\x, &x>0 .\end{cases}$ and $\frac{x}{|x|^{-1}}$ is just a funny way of writing $\text{sign}(x)$, where $\text{sign}(x) = \begin{cases}-1, & x<0,\\0, & x=0,\\+1, &x>0 .\end{cases}$

Comment: I edited my question. :-)

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia I edited my answer to reflect it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

$$(2|x|)'=2(|x|)'=2\left(\sqrt{x^2}\right)'=2\left(\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2}}\right)=2\frac x{\sqrt{x^2}}=2\frac x{|x|}$$